# Redirect example.com/path to different server but keep example.com/path

Tags: redirect, path, dns, subdomain

I feel like this is pretty straight forward but struggling to find a clear answer.

All I need to do is point `example.com/path` to a different server and keep `example.com/path` as the URL.

My question is: does the receiving server need to have its own domain to receive the redirect?

So, for example I would use a sub domain and point `example.com/path` -> `sub.example.com/path`?

How would I do this? Or is there a cleaner way?

We've been advised to keep the path as is (`example.com/path`) for SEO and not use a sub-domain (although, I suppose it's fine for redirect purposes).

Comment: Which web server software is used for main domain site (example.com)?

Comment: I believe it's Apache/2.2.22 from what I can see.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your main site's Virtual Host configuration:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /path http://any.other.example.com/path
ProxyPassReverse /path http://any.other.example.com/path
```

For this you need to have mod_proxy enabled, with this line in your httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
```

(but I believe it is enabled by default)